# diagrammeR (grViz) is looking for the data from environment rather than from the values inside shiny

Tags: r, shiny, diagrammer

I have below setup for diagram, the graph can only produces the below graph if I have `data` value in the environment, it's not looking at the data value I specified in the server at all. What should I do differently?

[image]

```
library(DiagrammeR)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  grVizOutput("parameter_plot"),
  numericInput("some_values", label = "Some values",
               value = 1, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Define some sample data
  output$parameter_plot <- renderGrViz({
    # Define some sample data
    data = tibble(a=1000,b=input$some_values,c=1000,d=1000,e=1000,f=1,g=1,h=1)
    
    
    
    DiagrammeR::grViz("
digraph graph2 {

graph [layout = dot]

# node definitions with substituted label text
node [shape = rectangle, style = filled]

node [fillcolor = lightblue]
a [label = '@@1']

node [fillcolor = Beige]
b [label = '@@2']
c [label = '@@3']
d [label = '@@4']

node [fillcolor = mediumpurple1]
e [label = '@@5']
f [label = '@@6']
g [label = '@@7']

node [fillcolor = darkseagreen1]
h [label = '@@8']
i [label = '@@9']


  subgraph cluster1 {
    node [fixedsize = true, width = 3]
    b -> {c d}
  }
  
  subgraph cluster2 {
    node [fixedsize = true, width = 3]
    e -> f -> g -> e
  }
  
  subgraph cluster3 {
    node [fixedsize = true, width = 3]
    h
    i
  }

a -> b 
a -> e
f -> i
e -> h

}

")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the footnotes at the end correctly it should work. In the example below I use `glue::glue` to insert code into the string. Part of label 1 comes from a `data.frame` and a part of label 6 comes from a `numericInput` and can be adjusted interactively.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

ui <- fluidPage(
  grVizOutput("parameter_plot"),
  numericInput("some_values", label = "Some values",
               value = 1, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Define some sample data
  output$parameter_plot <- renderGrViz({
    
    print(input$some_values)
    # Define some sample data
    data = tibble(a = 696,
                  b = input$some_values,
                  c = 1000,
                  d = 1000,
                  e = 1000,
                  f = 1,
                  g = 1,
                  h = 1)
    
    
    
    DiagrammeR::grViz(glue::glue(
      .open = "{{",
      .close = "}}", 
      
      "digraph graph2 {

graph [layout = dot]

# node definitions with substituted label text
node [shape = rectangle, style = filled]

node [fillcolor = lightblue]
a [label = '@@1']

node [fillcolor = Beige]
b [label = '@@2']
c [label = '@@3']
d [label = '@@4']

node [fillcolor = mediumpurple1]
e [label = '@@5']
f [label = '@@6']
g [label = '@@7']

node [fillcolor = darkseagreen1]
h [label = '@@8']
i [label = '@@9']

  subgraph cluster1 {
    node [fixedsize = true, width = 3]
    b -> {c d}
  }
  
  subgraph cluster2 {
    node [fixedsize = true, width = 3]
    e -> f -> g -> e
  }
  
  subgraph cluster3 {
    node [fixedsize = true, width = 3]
    h
    i
  }

a -> b 
a -> e
f -> i
e -> h

}

[1]: '1. Est.Demand (n = {{data$a}})'
[2]: 'Patient leaves pathway'
[3]: 'NAS: Discharged (n = 78)'
[4]: '2. ROTT (n = 8)'
[5]: '4. Clinical Slots Used (n = 665)'
[6]: 'Some values (n = {{input$some_values}})'
[7]: '7. NASL: Rebooked (n = 55)'
[8]: '6. NASL (n = 14)'
[9]: '8. Expected Attendences (n = 596)'

"))
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I need the labels as well, not just the number, how can I do it? Please refer to the picture in my question. I tried paste, but didn't work.

Comment: This is of course possible and I will adjust my answer later, however, it is not clear to me what label you want to change based on `input$some_values`.

Comment: Sure thanks, I want the input$some_values to be something like: "Some values: (n=input$some_values)", basically I want the variable values to be associated with a fixed text, please let me know if this is clear enough, my apology for not making this clear in my question, will edit it later.

Comment: I’m wondering if this is something possible to do? Or you will edit the answer later? Thanks!

Comment: It’s possible and I will edit my answer later.

Comment: @SubaruSpirit: I updated my answer. It should work now as expected. When defining the labels it is important to wrap them in  `''` like in `b [label = '@@2']`. I did not spot this at first, but without it I ran into a lot of errors.

Comment: I actually got them right, but didn't know need to use {{ }} to wrap them up! That's good thanks